# Error: nothing was specified to be included in the library when upgrading to flexmojos 4

Tags: maven, pom.xml, flexmojos, flex-mojos

I am trying to upgrade to flexmojos 4 from 3.9 and it is causing many issues (the maven build fails with lots of errors) and the main error seems to be:

Error: nothing was specified to be included in the library

And then it goes to tell you which classes are not defined (as a result of nothing being included in the library I assume). I did change  to  as required by the upgrade, anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the source directory inside your pom?

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/flex</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/flex</testSourceDirectory>
</build>
```

You may want to set the `includeClasses` property to flexmojo configuration:

```
<includeClasses>
   <scan>
     <includes>
        <include>org.htulipe.*</include>
     </includes>
   </scan>
</includeClasses>
```

If that does not work, could you provide more details about your build. What goal are you using? What your pom looks like?